# What is the mathematical formula representing this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following sequences that form a relationship:

*x*: 1  2  3  4  5
*y*: 1  2  4  8 16

Where each number in the second sequence is twice the previous number.

Is there a formula that will give me the correct value of *y* for a given value of *x*?  Does it have a name, and how could I have gone about working this out for myself?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $y=2^{x-1}$ and some characters

Comment: Wow, it's so simple when one can see it. Is this just something you *know*?

Comment: When the ratio of consecutive terms is constant (2, in this case), it is called geometric, and has the form $y = x_0r^{x-h}$, where $x_0$ is the first term and $r$ is the ratio.

Comment: @Neil: When you say each number is double the previous, that makes $2^n$ come to mind.  But checking that is off by a factor $2$, which is corrected by the $-1$

Comment: Ross Thanks so much for your swift answer.
@The Chaz - thank you for your helpful explanation.

Comment: @Neil: Anytime!

Comment: @Neil:  The expression from The Chaz has two constants, $x_0$ and $h$, which are redundant.  Two versions where $x_0'r^{-h'}=x_0r^{-h}$ will give the same sequence.

Comment: @Ross: It is possible to work around the character limit by hiding the padding in a HTML comment, like `<!-- this -->`.

Answer (score 1):

$y = 2^{x-1}$. This is a geometric sequence.